# java.lang.NullPointerException throws while using class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, classloader

When I'm using an referenced library, The NullPointerException have been thrown, it caused by: `InputStream inputStream = VersionInfoUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(VERSION_INFO_FILE);`

Why? when `getResourceAsStream()` can't find the file, it would return null, but won't throw a NullPointerException right?

I'm using Eclipse and I just drag the jar package into my project linked it in the properties. Did I miss something?

I want to know why and how to fix that?

Thinks

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--)?

Comment: Does the stack trace actually show it being thrown in that method, or by something it calls?

Answer (score 0):

I found out Class.getClassLoader() can return null in some specific situations, so the NullpointerException occurs